# Help with Chapter Headers Left-Aligning

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm using the following code for the top of chapters which looks pretty cool:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\raggedleft}
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}%
    \rlap{\resizebox{!}{1.5cm}{\thechapter} \rule{5cm}{1.5cm}}}
{10pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}
```

and it outputs chapter headers like this:
[image: Output it gives]

I would much prefer it if I were able to have chapter headings like this:
[image: Output I want]

How could I modify the code for this to work? I appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last argument of the `\titleformat` you just need to add `\raggedright` to have your chapter head left aligned. But, from a design point of view, I think it is better to align both to the right or both to the left.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\raggedleft}
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}%
    \rlap{\resizebox{!}{1.5cm}{\thechapter} \rule{5cm}{1.5cm}}}
{10pt}{\Huge\raggedright}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}

\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter Aligned Left}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\chapter{Third Chapter}
\end{document}
```